# Azure web app deployment CPU at 100% until restart

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, octopus-deploy

We have an issue where we deploy 16 APIs with Octopus and the overall cpu in Azure goes to 100% and won't fall back down until we restart the services. We are deploying APIs with webjobs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds similar to https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2090. If so, you should try the workaround proposed there, which is to set a `SCM_MAX_RANDOM_START_DELAY` App Setting to some value. This will avoid starting all the deployments at exactly the same time.

Comment: thanks for this. Before I mark your answer as correct, which is going to be a bit hard to prove, would you say that my issue is acceptable in terms of expecting Azure to just handle this? I don't think deploying 16 APIs should be that heavy a load but maybe it is? Or maybe our App Service Plan is to weak to handle this?

Comment: Yes, I do agree that ideally this would not be an issue in the first place. But as it stands, it does become an issue if you have many apps in the same App Service Plan and you deploy to all of them at the exact same time. What I suggested is more of a workaround, but should be effective.